# How to store a pandas dataframe with datetime.timedelta type data objects into a postgresql d/b using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I would like to store a pandas dataframe containing columns of type timedelta64 in a Postgresql database using sqlalchemy. Reading the documentation (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html) I expect that python 'timedelta' datatype could be mapped upon the postgresql 'interval' datatype, but I don't understand how to do this. I have tried the following code:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@floris/floris')

my_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[ timedelta(days=1), timedelta(days=2), timedelta(days=3)], index=range(0,3), columns=['delay'])

my_df.to_sql('my_table', con=engine, dtype={'delay': sa.types.Interval})
```

I got the following error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "delay" is of type interval but expression is of type bigint
LINE 1: INSERT INTO my_table (index, delay) VALUES (0, 8640000000000...
                                                       ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

It seems that sqlalchemy is not preserving the timedelta data type, but converting it to an bigint. How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timedelta is converted into integer values. Refer to
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/sql.py#L880-L883

A workaround would be converting the timedelta in string format, before saving it to db.

```
def a_func(val):
    return str(val)

my_df['delay'] = my_df['delay'].apply(a_func)
```

or

```
my_df['delay'] = my_df['delay'].astype(str)
```

Comment: @Ronald, pandas does not implement types the way python does. In most cases it is interchangeable. reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html