# timedelta64 column with apache superset

Tags: python, pandas, apache-superset

I have a dataframe with a `timedelta64` column that I want to use in my analytics. I upload the data to superset via "Upload CSV" and there doesn't seem to be a way to tell superset that a particular column is a timedelta during the upload process (similar to how you can tell it to parse specific columns as dates). So the column is imported as text and there is no way to change the type of column after the upload.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

the column types in Superset mirror the database column types. So if you upload a CSVS to a Postgres database, you need to make sure that timedelta is an actual column type (as far as I know, it isn't a column type!).

In fact, the suggested workaround is to save the value / column as string! [How to store a pandas dataframe with datetime.timedelta type data objects into a postgresql d/b using sqlalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516374/how-to-store-a-pandas-dataframe-with-datetime-timedelta-type-data-objects-into-a)

You can always tap into the semantic layer in Superset to continue transforming the data in SQL Lab: https://docs.preset.io/docs/semantic-layer